# Wine Mono closes on some functions

Tags: wine, mono

I may be confusing a few things here, but for definition, I believe that Mono is a program/plug-in in Wine that allows me to run dotnet (as in C.Net) programs.

I have been given a dotNet Program (that uses a 4.5 dotNet framework) and it runs fine in Mono, EXCEPT for a few functions malfunctioning.

Since it is not my program (and cannot fix it specifically for Ubuntu), I can only give a whitebox description:

- Opening a specific window (2 out of available 12 windows) in the Multi-Document Interface (MDI) would cause the program to close (which is stopped by an "Are you sure?" dialog)
- Editing the values or column widths of a Grid-based input window (DataGridView) would crash the program (no "Are you sure?" dialog).
- The 2 specific windows above contain populated DataGridViews as well
- Note that other windows with DataGridViews still open, but changing the column widths still crashes the program.

Just to clarify, the program is also installed in other Windows units in the office, and does not have any problems.

---

So, is this a naturally occurring thing, implying I need to get the C.net frameworks?

Or is there a fix, implying I just need to update or setup my Wine or Mono? (currently wine-mono4.5.6)

Comment: This [bug report] (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9653) confirms my claims. Only when I was typing this question did I find out about the link to datagridviews.

Answer (score 0):

Since this [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9653) has not been updated in a while, I have downloaded dotnet40 through winetricks, and my program now works.

```
$ ­wget http://winetricks.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/winetricks
$ bash winetricks dotnet40 corefonts
```

[Source](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17886)

Note that I had to try dotnet45, which failed to run my program. It seems there is a necessity to have the proper framework, rather than just the highest one available.